# Issues with initiating 9-patch drawables from input resources

Tags: android, drawable, nine-patch

Having kind of an issue with initiating 9patch drawables from input streams. I need to skin my app and need to download skin elements and images from a web service.

Sought through a reasonable amount of resources both in SO and android dev guides, but none seem to work for me.

Setting a drawable from a resource does handle 9patch properly so logically the smarts to do so is there, but for some reason the following code, **which I derived from the android sources itself**, fails to handle 9patch properly

```
     Rect pad = new Rect();
     BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
     opts.inScreenDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT;
     Bitmap  bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(resources, typedValue, new FileInputStream(path), pad, opts);
     if (bm != null) {
              byte[] np = bm.getNinePatchChunk();
              if (np == null || !NinePatch.isNinePatchChunk(np)) {
                       np = null;
                       pad = null;
              }
              if (np != null) {
                       drawable = new NinePatchDrawable(resources, bm, np, pad, path);
              } else {
                       drawable = new BitmapDrawable(resources, bm);
              }
     }
```

I have changed the input source to be the one of my files (FileInputStream(path)), in the android sources it is the input source initiated on resource images.

This code always returns BitmapDrawable even if the input image is a 9-patch.

Does anyone succeed actually getting this functionality working?
I'd appreciate any help or hint towards a solution.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the solution is that there's no solution here, because 9 patch requires nine patch chunk as an array which is being generated at compile time. Obviously we do not have a compile phase when loading images from a web resource.

To Android engineers - maybe future release of android SDKs will be able to generate the nine patch chunk at run time.

Answer (score 0):

I've created this gist to create 9patches at runtime: https://gist.github.com/4391807